# Confusion about when to use definite article when writing about "concepts"

Tags: definite-articles, uncountable-nouns, concept

Should the following sentences include a definite article?

- (The) management of different implementations is realised using a factory design pattern.
- There are two ways of measuring (the) availability: ...
- (The) availability is an important attribute.

While I believe that the words used are mass nouns, and I cannot conceptualise a single instance of, e.g., availability, I feel like the context suggests a more specific usage.

In general, I therefore often struggle with the decision whether or not to use a definite article. Existing guidelines I've read don't seem to help. Any advice on the mentioned examples?

Comment: +1 for seeking to improve the readability of technical documents.

Comment: I don't understand how anything about the use of articles could belong here rather than, for instance, at English Language Learners.